# Updating Items in Another List

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I have a point in my workflow where I need to update a field in another list with a value from my current list. I keep getting an error in my workflow that says "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user." I know that its not deleted, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Here's a clip of the Update Item Setup in SharePoint Designer:

[image: Item Status Update]

Basically, I am trying to take the choice (Open or Closed) in the Current Item "Item Status" field and update the "Item Status" field of the other list (User Assigned Invoices).
Thanks for any help or resources you can share.

Comment: Is the item in second list checked in?

Comment: I don't see an option to check it in. I created the list item by Creating a Line Item from the Current List, and now I just want to update a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My scenario is  update a field in another list. You can leave the variable and change others by your fields:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Sara!
For some reason, I am still confused on how to do this. I edited my image above to show the actual fields that I am using in both lists. I understand the reasoning behind using a unique ID for the item, but have never worked with that much. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going to item directly by "Reviewer 2" field. try finding the ID of the "Reviewer 2" field item in the other list. 
Here is what you should do:
1) In your workflow run a query to find item ID of the item where field is equals to your field "Reviewer 2"
2) run an update item action on second list where item ID is the one you found in above step.

Answer (score 0):

Am new to SharePoint but am going to give this a go anyways.

What I would do in your situation is have a column in *list A* that uniquely identifies each record. Lets call this column **RecId** [Primary key]. In *list B* You must have **RecId** as well as a [foreign key] so that when you come to the *update list dialogue box*, in the *find list item* section you can enter **RecId** in the *field* drop down and **CurentItem:RecId** in the *value* input box.

Now why you are having a problem is because you are not referencing the value you want between the two lists properly. *ItemStatus* is not a unique idetifier and there for it cannot be used as a reference. You need a corresponding *ID* of some sort just like what Sara in the above answer has used.